# Why isn't this rewrite rule (nginx) applied? (trying to setup Wordpress multisite)

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite, wordpress-mu

I'm trying to setup Wordpress multisite (subfolder structure) with nginx, but having a problem with this rewrite rule.

Below is the Apache's .htaccess, which I have to translate into nginx configuration.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Below is what I came up with:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    expires 1d;

    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    root /srv/www/example.com/public;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    # rewriting uploaded files
    rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?files/(.+) /blogs/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 last;

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?wp-admin$ /blogs/$1wp-admin/ permanent;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /blogs/$2 last;
        rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?(.*\.php)$ /blogs/$2 last;
    }

    location /blogs/ {
        index index.php;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /blogs/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/example.com/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # static assets
    location ~* ^.+\.(manifest)$ {
        access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/static.log; 
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ico|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        # only set expires max IFF the file is a static file and exists
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/static.log; 
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I believe `rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?(.*\.php)$ /blogs/$2 last;` has no effect because when I look at the access_log file, I see the following line:

```
2010/09/15 01:14:55 [error] 10166#0: *8 "/srv/www/example.com/public/blogs/test/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), request: "GET /blogs/test/ HTTP/1.1"
```

(Here, 'test' is the second blog created using multisite feature) What I'm expecting is that /blogs/test/index.php gets rewritten to /blogs/index.php, but it doesn't seem to do that...

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I don't think you're going to get away with changing `[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+` to `.+` in your rewrite rules, but I don't think that's what's biting you here.

The rule `rewrite ^/blogs/(.+/)?(.*\.php)$ /blogs/$2 last;` isn't matching `/blogs/test/index.php` because the request is actually for `/blogs/test/`. The `index.php` isn't tacked on until four lines later, when Nginx looks for the index file for that directory. If I'm right, `/blogs/test/` won't get rewritten, but `/blogs/test/index.php` (as put in the browser location bar) will.

That said, I think even then you might find that the `(.+/)?` part of the request matches nothing, and the `(.*\.php)` part matches the entirety of `test/index.php` resulting in essentially no rewriting at all, because of your imprecise wildcards as I noted in the first paragraph.